# How to get Angular app working with Cloudflare Workers - Workers Sites

Tags: angular, single-page-application, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I am struggling to get an SPA working using Angular with Cloudflare's Workers Sites. I am following the tutorial found [here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/tutorials/deploy-a-react-app/) (but supplementing steps for Angular- not React), and everything is fine until however once published I am getting the browser error - could not find index.html in your content namespace

My troubleshooting thus far has let me to link below:

https://github.com/cloudflare/kv-asset-handler#servesinglepageapp

however I am unsure how to configure/use this guidance for Angular so that it solves my above problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wrangler.toml` file should have the build folder on `[site].bucket` pointing to `./dist/<name-of-the-project>` instead of `./build` as seen in the guide.